# Dynamic Form validation is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

Scenario: User want to retrieve email or reset password. Person will select respective option as per requirement. Submit button will get enable only when form is valid.

Problem: 
I want to dynamically update validation according to selected option. But it is not working. Definitely  I'm missing something. I used clearValidators, but it is also not working. Here is the 
[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-41rbvx?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts).

For testing use: 
email : test@test.com
password: Test@1234

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try updating the individual controls value and validity. For example

```
this.loginTroubleForm.get('email').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Do this for each control for which you are setting the validator to null.

Comment: Thank You  Ritesh, It is working but don't you think its very bad practice to put updateValueAndValidity for each and every control